# How do I reference a input element from higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, ref, higher-order-components

I would like to access the input element from my HOC. How can I achieve this?

```
const TextInput = (props) => {  
const allowed = ['readOnly','tabIndex','placeholder'];
const filteredProps = filterProps(props,allowed);

    return (
        <div>
            <label>{props.field.Name}</label>
            <input type="text" ref={props.inputRef}   key={props.field.Id} className="form-control" id={props.field.Id} name={props.field.Name}
                value={props.value}
                onChange={props.onChange}
                onKeyDown={props.onKeyDown}
                {...filteredProps}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
TextInput.propTypes = {
    fieldMetadata: PropTypes.object,
    isValid: PropTypes.bool
}
export default withInputMask(withRequired(withReadOnly(withMinMax(withHidden(TextInput)))));
```

I have tried a few things but this is the latest attempt. 
Inside the withInputMask render method I have inserted the following.

```
            return (
                <div>
                    <Component {...this.props} inputRef={el=> this.inputElement=el} isValid={isValid} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder={inputMaskPattern} />
                    {hasErrors && <span className={hasErrors}>{error}</span>}
                </div>

            );
        }
    }
};
export default withInputMask;
```

when I open the react dev tools and click on withInputMask component this is what I see.

[image]

Comment: The above now works as expected. Referenced and verified using [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: The only issue now is that this.inputElement is undefined inside componentDidMount() of my HOC, why is that?